# Java Nashorn compatibility file crashes

Tags: java, runtimeexception, nashorn

When I try to load the Nashorn compatibility file for Rhino (`load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js")`) it comes up with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "net" is not defined in nashorn:mozilla_compat.js at line number 67
```

I've tried everything to get it to work but nothing has helped :(

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if your script (not `mozilla_compat.js` itself) contains a declaration with a qualified name like this:

```js
var x = new net.yourdomain.yourpackage.ClassName();
```

instead of doing

```js
importPackage(Packages.net.yourdomain.yourpackage);

var x = new ClassName();
```

The former works in Rhino, but not in Nashorn, even with the compatibility script. The latter however will work in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code with the latest JDK 8 update released (8u60) - available for download @ http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception {
      ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");
      e.eval("load('nashorn:mozilla_compat.js')");
      // this should print 'function' and mozilla_compat.js defines that function
      e.eval("print(typeof importClass)");    
   }
}
```

And it printed "function" as expected. I checked it on jdk9-dev tip forest build as well. It works with that version as well. Will you please print "java -version" and make sure you're using recent JDK 8 ?

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)

Comment: I used the same - on Windows 7 machine  (which shouldn't make a difference). And you used the above program that I've in my reply? (just to be sure..)